# Binding Jetty HttpClient to Network Interface Card

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9, jetty-httpclient

I will be using Jetty HttpClient on machines with two Network Interface Cards, I want the ability to force (bind) Jetty HttpClient to one of the NICs, would this be possible with Jetty HttpClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`HttpClient.setBindAddress(java.net.SocketAddress)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html#setBindAddress-java.net.SocketAddress-) to set the address of the NIC you want to bind the output requests against.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it as httpClient.setBindAddress(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.129", 81)); It looks like it works, but if I run the program again it says "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: no further information" and I would have to give it another port number.

Comment: Use port 0, for outgoing connections you don't need to specify one.

Comment: Can you also take a look at another question from me regarding Jetty? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781131/traffic-in-fiddler-from-jetty-httpclient-while-using-https